# Table border is not drawn

Tags: tables

Why is the edge is not drawn?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \begin{tabular}[]{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{c|}{aaaaa} \\
      \hline
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
    \end{document}
```

And the not wanted result (see red circle):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed adding an leading `|` in `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{aaaaa} \\`.

with the code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \begin{tabular}[]{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
      \hline
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
    \end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: how write in bold font the title?